# Is there a reason why someone would include stdlib.h twice?

Tags: c

I was studying the code for the Kilo text editor here:

https://github.com/antirez/kilo/blob/master/kilo.c

And I noticed that the includes defined `stdlib.h` twice (UPDATE: Comments are mine):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // first time
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // second time
#include <ctype.h>
```

Is this merely an error? Or is there something to it? I ask because the author of the code doesn't seem like someone who makes a lot of mistakes. I wouldn't want to suggest a change in ignorance.

Comment: @alk yeah I identified the wrong line of code. It's the one just above. Have fixed.

Comment: "*include stdlib.h twice?*" I'd consider this sloppiness. And no, for a correct implementation the 2nd include does no harm, in fact is a NOP.

Comment: Hopefully just an oversight. I'd be surprised if stdlib.h didn't do "the dance of the ifdefs" which makes the second inclusion effectively a NoOP.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry those comments were mine not his!

Comment: Should have included an `include guard` to have prevented from seeing twice by the compiler. To make no harm to the existing code, just add the guard and you need not worry of any impacts the 2nd inclusion!

Comment: Did you have a look at `stdlib.h` code? Did you notice something right at the beginning (something like `#ifndef STDLIB_H #define STDLIB_H`? WHat does that tell you?

Comment: @Olaf I am new to C, but I do understand the principal involved. My question, in case it wasn't clear, was whether there was some esoteric trick being used. I like to be sure of something before I go telling more experienced people they've made a mistake. It's called humility. Terrible habit.

Comment: @DanielC You *can* play tricks with muliple includes, as my answer is indicating. Though in your case all of the includes are standard and probably not doing so.

Comment: The code is open to be read, you can see what it does and examin the guards. So what "tricks" are to be expected? It is a good practice for a beginner, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stdlib.h has an include guard, there is no point in including it twice. Probably the mistake was caused by merging two files, both dependant on stdlib.h.

Comment: "*has an include guard*" hopefully it has. We do not know which implementations are around.

Comment: @alk Do you know of an implementation that does _not_ have include guards in the standard headers?

Comment: No, but there's a lot I don't know ... ;-)

Comment: @alk But the world is a strange place, so one should probably avoid double includes in any case...

Answer (score 3):

There is no harm in including a standard header more than once, although it is totally unnecessary.

The [C standard says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2p4) the following about this:

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included
>   more than once in a given scope, with no effect different from being
>   included only once, except that the effect of including `<assert.h>`
>   depends on the definition of `NDEBUG`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to include a particular header file twice.  If the file has proper include guards, the second inclusion will have no effect.  If it does not have include guards, you'll likely get a slew of errors for multiple definitions for typedefs, among others.

In the case of system headers, they almost always have include guards.  The contents of stdlib.h might look something like this:

```
#ifndef _STDLIB_H
#define _STDLIB_H   1
...
// type definitions, #defines, declarations, etc.
...
#endif /* stdlib.h  */
```

The first time stdlib.h is included, the `#ifndef` will evaluate to true, `_STDLIB_H` is defined, and the remaining contents are inserted into the file being compiled.  The second time stdlib.h is included, the `#ifndef` will evaluate to false since `_STDLIB_H` is defined and the contents of the file between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` will not be inserted again.

Most UNIX/Linux systems do this.  In contrast, Microsoft is known for not managing its OS specific include files properly.  If you included them in the wrong order you'll end up with lots of errors.

Answer (score 1):

The only scenario it can make a difference is when one of the includes is *undefining* some symbols (including the include guards) from the previous includes. Consider 2 files:
**1.h:**

```
#define A 1
```

**2.h**:

```
#undef A
```

Now, the following sequence:

```
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"

int B = A;
```

will produce an error, as `A` is undefined.

The following sequence will be just fine:

```
#include "1.h"
#include "2.h"
#include "1.h"

int B = A;
```

Now, if `1.h` has the include guards:

**1.h:**

```
#ifndef GUARD_1
#define GUARD_1
#define A 1
#endif
```

The **2.h** can do:

```
#undef GUARD_1
#undef A
```

and cause the same effect.

Now to `stdlib.h`. You can compose something like this in your **x.h** header:

```
#undef _STDLIB_H   // Kill the include guard of stdlib.h
#undef NULL        // Undefine some important symbol from stdlib.h
```

Now, this sequence:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "x.h"
```

will have `NULL` undefined

And this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "x.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

will have it defined.

Answer (score 0):

Though not directly applicable to `<stdlib.h>`, a reason for including a user-defined header file twice: Testing if including the header file twice incurs a problem.

Example: Consider a pair of files `foo.h` and `foo.c` declaring and implementing a bunch of `foo_` functions, defines, types, etc.

File `foo.c`

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.h"

rest of foo.c code ...
```

A 2nd calling of an include file should not cause a problem and `foo.c` tests that.
OTOH,  `foo.c` did not test if including a header file only once is OK.